# Read user installed certificates in Android

Tags: android, security, ssl-certificate

I'm developing an Android app which uses a self-signed certificate to get data from each user (it is a private client app).

The application can read all trusted certificates (system and user), but the certificate I installed and all others that I install appear to be in "User credentials", and can't be access with the AndroidCAStore.

I am missing something? It is the problem of the certificate or the way I'm searching it? If someone has done this before please explain how to get the data from my own installed certificates because I don't know where to go now.

I have searched through all the internet and haven't found anything for this... Thanks in advance!

Comment: For what purpose do you use the certificate? If the certificate is only used within your app and it has a private key you should better use the `AndroidKeyStore`.

Comment: @Robert AndroidKeyStore can't be used because it is a client certificate so it doesn't get stored there, it goes to "User credentials" which is not accesible from there as far as I know

Comment: Client certificates can be stored (imported) in the `AndroidKeyStore` as well. Where to save just depends on the purpose the client cert should be used for.

Comment: How can I access "User credentials" (where it is stored the certificate I need) from AndroidKeyStore? @Robert

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore

Comment: @maryrio7 did you get solution of this problem ?